# How do I define a Dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am doing some work in a jupyter notebook using python and pandas and am getting a weird error message and would really appreciate the help. The error I am receiving is "NameError: name 'DataFrame' is not defined"

```
import pandas as pd 

d = {'name': ['Braund', 'Cummings', 'Heikkinen', 'Allen'],
     'age': [22,38,26,35],
     'fare': [7.25, 71.83, 0 , 8.05], 
     'survived?': [False, True, True, False]}

df = DataFrame(d)

print(df)
```

Comment: Go read a tutorial on Python import statements. The way it's written here forces you to use `pd.DataFrame`

Comment: You need to do `df = pd.DataFrame(d)`. Giving your imported module an alias(`pd`) does not automatically import the modules namespace. If you wan to keep your code the way it is, use `from panda import *`. I recommend the former.

Answer (score 18):

The below code works:

```
import pandas as pd 

d = {'name': ['Braund', 'Cummings', 'Heikkinen', 'Allen'],
     'age': [22,38,26,35],
     'fare': [7.25, 71.83, 0 , 8.05], 
     'survived?': [False, True, True, False]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df)
```

Instead of:

```
DataFrame(d)
```

You have to do:

```
pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Because you've imported pandas as 'pd'.

You can achieve the same end much better by:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Braund', 'Cummings', 'Heikkinen', 'Allen'],
                   'age': [22,38,26,35],
                   'fare': [7.25, 71.83, 0 , 8.05], 
                   'survived': [False, True, True, False]})
```

I removed the '?' from the 'survived' feature as it's not a good idea to have special characters in your feature names.

Comment: Coming back to this over a year later and much deeper into my understanding of pandas and data science this is pretty freaking comical. Rookie move on my part.

Comment: We all start from somewhere :)

Answer (score 9):

The error is not weird. Adding following statement at the top solves the problem:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
```